# How do you split elements in an array and return it as a new array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, linq

I have a array of string in following format.

```
string[] sports = { "Cricket" ,  "Football"  ,"Boxing/Tennis " , "Soccer"} ;
```

Is there any built in way in C# or using LINQ to split strings in array
and return new array like

```
string[] sportsNewArray = { "Cricket" ,  "Football"  ,"Boxing" , "Tenis " , "Soccer"} ;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
string[] sportsNewArray = sports.SelectMany(s=>s.Split('/')).ToArray();
```

Comment: :) yes, but SelectMany is not so "known", although is widely used in LINQ queries (from s in sports from sport in s.Split('/') select sport)